# Created a fund manager program with python but .exe file wont work on another computer

Tags: python, tkinter

I hope you're doing well. I have a question. I created a fund manager program that keep track of investment accounts and profits. it works fine on one computer. I used the prompt --onefile to create a .exe file to use this program on other computers but its not working. When i try it, the terminal opens but it closes instantly.

Would anyone be able to give me some recommendations?

Thank you

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, simpledialog, messagebox, filedialog
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk
from tkinter import PhotoImage, Label
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk



# Define hover functions
def on_enter(e):
    e.widget.config(background='red')

def on_leave(e):
    e.widget.config(background='#cecdcd')


class Investor:
    def __init__(self, name, initial_investment, is_manager=False):
        self.name = name
        self.initial_investment = initial_investment
        self.additional_investments = 0.0
        self.total_investment = initial_investment
        self.is_manager = is_manager
        self.ownership_percentage = 0.0
        self.current_balance = initial_investment
        self.total_profit = 0.0
        self.roi = 0.0
        self.management_fee = 0.0


    def calculate_profit_and_roi(self, total_fund_balance):
        self.ownership_percentage = self.total_investment / fund.total_investment if fund.total_investment else 0
        self.current_balance = total_fund_balance * self.ownership_percentage
        self.total_profit = self.current_balance - self.total_investment
        self.roi = (self.total_profit / self.total_investment) * 100 if self.total_investment else 0


    def calculate_management_fee(self):
        if not self.is_manager and self.name != "Crystal":
            self.management_fee = self.total_profit * 0.20
            self.total_profit -= self.management_fee
        else:
            self.management_fee = 0


    def update_investment(self, additional_amount=0):
        self.additional_investments += additional_amount
        self.total_investment = self.initial_investment + self.additional_investments


class HedgeFund:
    def __init__(self):
        self.investors = []
        self.total_investment = 0.0
        self.total_fund_balance = 0.0


    def update_investments(self):
        self.total_investment = sum(investor.total_investment for investor in self.investors)
        for investor in self.investors:
            investor.calculate_profit_and_roi(self.total_fund_balance)


    def calculate_gains(self, gain_percentage):
        # Make sure to update total fund balance correctly
        self.total_fund_balance = self.total_investment * (1 + gain_percentage / 100)


        for investor in self.investors:
            investor.calculate_profit_and_roi(self.total_fund_balance)
            investor.calculate_management_fee()


        # Distribute collected management fees to the manager
        total_management_fee_collected = sum(investor.management_fee for investor in self.investors if investor.name != "Crystal" and not investor.is_manager)
        for investor in self.investors:
            if investor.is_manager:
                investor.total_profit += total_management_fee_collected
                break


        update_display()


    def add_investor(self, name, investment, is_manager=False):
        investor = Investor(name, investment, is_manager)
        self.investors.append(investor)
        investor.update_investment()
        self.update_investments()


    def save_data(self, filename):
        data = {
            "total_fund_balance": self.total_fund_balance,
            "investors": {investor.name: investor.__dict__ for investor in self.investors}
        }
        with open(filename, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(data, file, indent=4)


    def load_data(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
        self.total_fund_balance = data["total_fund_balance"]
        self.investors.clear()
        for name, investor_data in data["investors"].items():
            new_investor = Investor(name, 0)
            new_investor.__dict__.update(investor_data)
            self.investors.append(new_investor)
        self.update_investments()
        update_display()


fund = HedgeFund()


def add_investor():
    name = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "Investor Name:", parent=root)
    investment = simpledialog.askfloat("Input", "Initial Investment:", parent=root)
    is_manager = messagebox.askyesno("Input", "Is this investor the manager?", parent=root)
    if name and investment is not None:
        fund.add_investor(name, investment, is_manager)
        update_display()


def add_additional_investment():
    name = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "Investor Name for Additional Investment:", parent=root)
    additional_investment = simpledialog.askfloat("Input", "Additional Investment Amount:", parent=root)
    if name and additional_investment is not None:
        for investor in fund.investors:
            if investor.name == name:
                investor.update_investment(additional_investment)
                fund.update_investments()
                update_display()


def calculate_gains():
    gain_percentage = simpledialog.askfloat("Input", "Enter Total Fund Gain Percentage:", parent=root)
    if gain_percentage is not None:
        fund.calculate_gains(gain_percentage)


def save_data():
    filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".json", filetypes=[("JSON Files", "*.json")], parent=root)
    if filename:
        fund.save_data(filename)


def load_data():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("JSON Files", "*.json")], parent=root)
    if filename:
        fund.load_data(filename)


def update_display():
    total_profit = sum(investor.total_profit for investor in fund.investors)
    total_management_fee = sum(investor.management_fee for investor in fund.investors)
    total_investment = fund.total_investment
    total_ownership = sum(investor.ownership_percentage for investor in fund.investors) * 100
    total_balance = fund.total_fund_balance  # This represents the total balance

    total_profit_label.config(text=f"Total Profit: {total_profit:.2f}")
    total_management_fee_label.config(text=f"Total Management Fee: {total_management_fee:.2f}")
    total_investment_label.config(text=f"Total Investment: {total_investment:.2f}")
    total_ownership_label.config(text=f"Total Ownership: {total_ownership:.2f}%")
    total_balance_label.config(text=f"Total Balance: {total_balance:.2f}")

    for i in tree.get_children():
        tree.delete(i)
    for investor in fund.investors:
        tree.insert("", "end", values=(
            investor.name, investor.total_investment, 
            f"{investor.ownership_percentage*100:.2f}%", 
            investor.current_balance, investor.total_profit, 
            f"{investor.roi:.2f}%", investor.management_fee))


def show_ownership_chart():
    # Create a Toplevel window
    chart_window = tk.Toplevel(root) 
    chart_window.title("Ownership Chart")

    # Create a figure for the pie chart
    fig = Figure(figsize=(6, 6))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    # Data for pie chart
    ownerships = [investor.ownership_percentage for investor in fund.investors]
    names = [investor.name for investor in fund.investors]

    # Create the pie chart
    ax.pie(ownerships, labels=names, autopct='%1.1f%%')  # Adjust as needed

    # Embed the figure in the Tkinter window
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=chart_window)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    # Add a Close button
    close_button = tk.Button(chart_window, text="Close", command=chart_window.destroy)
    close_button.pack()



root = ThemedTk(theme="elegance")
root.title("Apex Capital® Fund Manager")

# Set custom window icon
root.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\jguarino\Desktop\Favicon.ico')

# New logo code here
original_image = Image.open('C:\\Users\\jguarino\\Desktop\\APEX_LOGO.png')
resized_image = original_image.resize((152, 42))  # Adjust size as needed
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
logo_label = tk.Label(root, image=logo)
logo_label.pack(anchor='center', padx=10, pady=10)

# Create a style object
style = ttk.Style(root)

# Frame for the treeview
tree_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
tree_frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

tree = ttk.Treeview(tree_frame, columns=("Name", "Total Investment", "Ownership", "Balance", "Profit", "ROI", "Management Fee"))
for col in tree["columns"]:
    tree.heading(col, text=col)
tree['show'] = 'headings'
tree.pack(expand=True, fill='both')



# Frame for the buttons
button_frame = tk.Frame(root)
button_frame.pack()

# Custom style for buttons
button_style = {'font': ('Arial', 10), 'background': '#cecdcd', 'foreground': 'Black'}


# Apply custom style to buttons and pack them
add_investor_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Add Investor", command=add_investor, **button_style)
add_investor_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
add_investor_button.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
add_investor_button.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)

add_additional_investment_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Add Additional Investment", command=add_additional_investment, **button_style)
add_additional_investment_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
add_additional_investment_button.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
add_additional_investment_button.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)

calculate_gains_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Calculate Gains", command=calculate_gains, **button_style)
calculate_gains_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
calculate_gains_button.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
calculate_gains_button.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)

save_data_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Save Data", command=save_data, **button_style)
save_data_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
save_data_button.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
save_data_button.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)

load_data_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Load Data", command=load_data, **button_style)
load_data_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
load_data_button.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
load_data_button.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)


show_chart_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Show Ownership Chart", command=show_ownership_chart, **button_style)
show_chart_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
show_chart_button.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
show_chart_button.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)




# Frame for total values
total_values_frame = tk.Frame(root)
total_values_frame.pack()

# Custom style for labels
label_style = {'font': ('Arial', 10), 'background': '#f1f0f0', 'foreground': 'red'}

# Apply custom style to labels and pack them
total_investment_label = tk.Label(total_values_frame, text="Total Investment: 0.00", **label_style)
total_investment_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

total_ownership_label = tk.Label(total_values_frame, text="Total Ownership: 0.00%", **label_style)
total_ownership_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

total_profit_label = tk.Label(total_values_frame, text="Total Profit: 0.00", **label_style)
total_profit_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

total_management_fee_label = tk.Label(total_values_frame, text="Total Management Fee: 0.00", **label_style)
total_management_fee_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

total_balance_label = tk.Label(total_values_frame, text="Total Balance: 0.00", **label_style)
total_balance_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)



root.mainloop()
```

I tried everything. shut off anti virus, changed path links, etc.

Comment: *"When i try it, the terminal opens but it closes instantly."* - When you try to execute the program from a terminal that's already open, does the program output anything?

Comment: does the `exe` work on this _"one computer"_ or just the python script that works ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You use an absolute path for an icon file and an image file, do they exist in another computer?